# Google Product's Data fetching

Tags: android, zxing, product

I am wondering one thing, when you scan a bar code with ZXing scanner,  how to go and get the result of the barcode data from Google Product database ?
I already got a database to store the scanned result btw.
I have no clue recently though I have read some of the stackoverflow topics regarding with this topic.

Research that I have done so far: 
I have been looking into this :https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/getting-started/usingapi-products
But I don't understand... because i m not sure if Android includes the JSon and Atom?

I know this question is so general but I need some explanations as well because I didn't understand it.Thank you ! :)

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question afterwards and "change" the question because of my hint of Google's Search API. Yes, you did some research..but after you read my post -_-. Use comments. So..based on your new question see the last comment of my answer (atom == xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply search barcodes by opening the browser with the following URL: http://www.google.com/m/products?q=YOUR_BARCODE

Or you can use Google Search API for Shopping if you like to handle the result on your own (show results/offers in your app). In that case you are restricted to 2500 requests per day (http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html)

Comment: Hi, yes, I would like to handle the product's result eg, name of the product and the price.

Comment: See the link I posted. There is everything described. You can use your Google account and activate the Search API service. This will generate a key. That key you have to use for your HTTP requests for authentification. Use the "q" parameter for the barcode

Comment: btw: you will get a XML file as respone (you can also get JSOn output). The only thing you have to do is to parse your relevant information

Comment: no, I did research before I read your post as well !but I just didn't copy it down..but yes, you are right, i should not edit it so that the flow of the research changed ! :D anyway thanks for the comment, I will research about JSON again.

Comment: ok has been 15 min researching about what is ATOM or JSON , really what are they? for example, i don't understand its code <s:facets>
? what does it want to mean?

Comment: i found this : http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp seems like they are nearly the same?

Comment: To make it clear: Where do you stuck? Maybe you don't know what to do with that XML (atom)/JSON respone? Or the difference between XML and JSON? Or the meaning of some tags like "facets"?

Comment: hi yes, i know XML but I don't know the code. What do I have to read for basics? and yes something like s:facets , what does it mean?

Comment: There are dozens of tutorials for parsing XML/JSON from internet.  You can google or have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793809/android-xml-parsing-from-internet. This may help you getting startet